# pickle data was truncated con cliente remoto

Tags: python, socket, pickle

Estoy teniendo problemas usando los sockets. Digamos que tengo un servidor que me manda mensajes a los clientes conectados. He mirado el tamaño del mensaje y nunca excede de 16384 bytes. Yo en bind, le pongo un hostname y me conecto a el remotamente desde otra maquina, o con un cliente desde la misma. El problema viene cuando me conecto desde otra máquina, recibiendo el mensaje así:

```
msg = sock.recv(16384)
tick_dict = pickle.loads(msg)
data_handler.update_dataframes(tick_dict)
```

A veces recibo: "_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated"

Para clientes conectados en la misma máquina no hay problema, solo me pasa cuando es uno remoto. El mensaje es el mismo para los dos clientes, tanto uno local como uno remoto, ¿por qué uno lo recibe y el otro no?

Envío el mensaje con

```
msg = pickle.dump(tick_dict)
socket.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás asumiendo dos cosas que no debes asumir:

- El bloque enviado por `send` no se fragmenta nunca.
- `recv` recibe siempre los bytes pedidos y no retorna hasta que no los tiene todos.

El bloque puede fragmentarse, de hecho dado tu tamaño de bloque lo normal es que a través de una red lo haga. `recv` no espera a tener `x` bytes,
`recv` espera a tener algo y de ese algo toma como máximo `x` bytes.

TCP está orientado a la transmisión, busca que los datos lleguen todos, íntegros y en el orden enviados, lo que no establece es cuando, ni el tamaño de los bloques. Debido a mil cosas como paquetes perdidos, cantidad de datos pendientes por enviar, infraestructura de la red, etc no puedes asumir nunca que si envías 512 bytes `recv` a a recibir esos 512 bytes en un solo paquetito, puede que si o puede que no.

El receptor en TCP solo sabe que está recibiendo una secuencia de bytes, punto. Podría obtener desde el primer byte hasta el tamaño de búfer totalmente solicitado en cualquier `recv` o no. **No existe una correlación uno a uno entre la llamada a `send` en un lado y la llamada de `recv` en el otro.**

Los protocolos de nivel superior implementados sobre sockets TCP resuelven el problemas con distintos enfoques, HTTP lo que hace es enviar una cabecera con los bytes que va a enviar delimitada por `\r\n`, luego el cliente itera hasta que los tiene todos, no tiene ni pajolera idea de cuantas veces tendrá que iterar, pero al menos sabe cuanto va a recibir si no hay una catástrofe de por medio. Otra posibilidad es usar banderas como `NUL` o una secuencia de bytes prefijados en tamaño y contenido que marcan el inicio o final de un mensaje o su tamaño.

Cuando llamas a `recv` pueden pasar muchas cosas:

- No hay un solo byte en el buffer -> esperará hasta que llegue algo, eternamente o el tiempo de espera indicado si lo hacemos.
- Hay datos, pero no todo el bloque esperado -> Obtendrás esa parte de inmediato, le importa un pimiento lo que quede por llegar.
- Hay más de 16384 bytes disponibles -> Obtendrá 16384 y el resto los deja en el buffer.
- El servido  ha cerrado el socket -> Obtendrá 0 bytes de datos.
- El servidor ha restablecido la conexión o cualquier otra posibilidad no contemplada antes -> Excepción al canto...

Debes establecer un protocolo por tanto que le permita al cliente saaber cuando el servidor le envión todos los datos, por ejemplo, puedes enviar una cabecera con los bytes que vas a enviar, delimitada por `\r`:

**`servidor.py`**

```
import pickle
import socket

import pandas as pd


test_df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": range(1000), "bar": range(1000, 2000)})
buffer = pickle.dumps(test_df)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        n_bytes = connection.send(str(len(buffer)).encode() + b"\r")
        connection.sendall(buffer)            
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

**`cliente.py`**

```
import io
import socket
import pickle

import pandas as pd


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 10000)
sock.connect(server_address)

try:
    n_bytes = b""
    byte = None
    while byte != b"\r":
        byte = sock.recv(1)
        n_bytes += byte

    n_bytes = int(n_bytes)
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    recibidos = 0
    while recibidos < n_bytes:
        msg = sock.recv(1024)
        buffer.write(msg)
        recibidos += len(msg)
    buffer.seek(0)
    tick_dict = pickle.loads(buffer.read())
    print(tick_dict)

finally:
    sock.close()
```